# Rails 4 fails to load assets in dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In production all works fine. I am using a Mac Book Pro as dev env.
In development I am getting these (several) errors:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
When trying to load from http://localhosts:8080/assets ...
Not sure why rails is not loading from public/assets?
What is wrong here?
And after restarting the server I am getting this error:
Errno::EINVAL
Invalid argument

```
      connection.connect_unix(config[:path], connect_timeout)
    else
      connection.connect(config[:host], config[:port], connect_timeout)
    end

    instance = new(connection)
```

What is wrong with my dev env?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the rack-cors gem.
Problem solved.